# Randomly Generating Numbers Input for MS-Word

Tags: c#, math, ms-word

I'm trying to help a kid practice some basic arithmetic. I want to create worksheets everyday that are new.
I've never really made a stand-alone program before. Only used Unity + C#. Still fairly new.

How do I create a program that automatically inputs:

*. <3DigitRandomNumber> + <3DigitRandomNumber> =*

Multiple times on Microsoft Word or any text editing program.
It doesn't have to be on another program. I could do it manually on a console too but that takes the fun out of making a program.

Fairly simple, right? The end result should look like a whole worksheet to practice math.

- **1.** 712 + 213 =
- **2.** 828 + 124 =
- **3.** *and so on...*

Comment: Have a look at the Random class. It's pseudo-random, but that's good enough for your needs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: As far as directly writing to a word document, that's a little harder. You might want to start by just writing lines to a plain .txt file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file

Comment: [How to Create Word Document Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/) - you might need .NET instead of C# Mono though.

Comment: Try creating an HTML document instead of a Word document; HTML is much simpler, and HTML can be displayed and printed by any browser, and, I believe, MS Word as well. Your C# program might be simply something to print a few HTML tags and random numbers. Good luck and have fun.